# Problems with fe_login

Tags: authentication, frontend, typo3

I have a problem with TYPO3's front end user login extension, It correctly detects correct logins and logouts but if I enter an incorrect user/password combination then It doesn't show any error or warning message (which are defined).

I've tried to trace the extension code and print all states and request values and discovered that once incorrect login attempt is detected it "erases" any session or request variable like  It would be the first time a user enters the page.

I am using TYPO3 4.5.2, if any one has a clue about what's going on it would really helpful.

Comment: You are using system extension feedit? Which version? Do you are using it in englisch or an translated version? You checked the HTML code, so nothing is hidden via css?

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- Try to test this behaviour without being logged into the backend
  (e.g. in another browser).
- Update TYPO3 (or felogin extension).
- Cookie handling might be an issue, too:

  - Delete all cookies from your domain
  - Check if setting `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['cookieDomain']` ins localconf.php resolves the issue [[Howto]](http://www.typo3.net/backendkonfiguration/systemkonfiguration/#cookieDomain)